# Styling Actionbar Appcompat devider

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am working on an app where I have to modify the app Actionbar. I am able to design it according to the requirement, but facing problem in designing the white line beneath the action bar. Well, I have got some hack where I can take the view and design it. But I want it to style it using style.xml.

**EDIT**

Now google has released toolbar that you can modify easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style your action bar like the below code -

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

and also please check the link - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html to get more information. Hope it helped you.

Comment: It's for changing background color not for drawing line below the actionbar.

Comment: Generate a theme. It will give you a zip of drawables and style.xml. Try to replace the drawable for action bar background. A little odd, but can work.